# Follow Company Button -- LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

Is it normal that LinkedIn's company follow button opens a blank page? The button comes from a javascript snippet provided by LinkedIn.

I tried on Chrome and Edge, and nothing happends (only a blank page). I think the problem comes from LinkedIn because they have the same problem at https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company

Try to make a button and click on it.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

The LinkedIn follow button widget works but it shows an odd behavior of directing you to a blank page. Notice the (not so obvious) +1 in the follow count in the widget. This happens for both logged in and not logged in LinkedIn users.

If you are not logged in to your account in LinkedIn and clicks on the follow button on a different tab/window, a popup will show up and prompts you to log in to LinkedIn. After logging in, it will open a new blank page.

But if you are already logged in to your account and clicks on the follow button, it will just open a new blank page.

Comment: hi thank you for your reply. Yes i know that but it's not professional for my customers. Apparently, the API have the same result. Do you think they will fix it?

Comment: @badre best to ask LinkedIn about it.